# Ajuda com aplicaçao e Android Studio

Tags: android

Eu fiz uma aplicaçao, e agora mudei o  minSdkVersion  para que rode em versoes anteriores do android.  So que ao instalar o mesmo no emulador funciona normalmente, mas ao instalar no celular ele me da a seguinte mensagem: O

> aplicativo parou.

fiz esta configuraçoes

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.flextelecom.barbacena"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/jtds-1.3.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Versao 2.3 parece que a Asynctask tben nao roda

```
08-01 12:36:36.889 1149-1997/br.com.flextelecom.barbacena E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
 at      java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
 Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore
   at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:359)
   at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:180)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:145)
   at br.com.flextelecom.barbacena.Conexoes_Banco.ConexaoDao.dbConnect(ConexaoDao.java:31)
   at br.com.flextelecom.barbacena.Conexoes_Banco.DaoCaptRioMortes.nomeTabela(DaoCaptRioMortes.java:55)
   at br.com.flextelecom.barbacena.Actions_Main.Act_Capt_RioMortes$MinhaTask.doInBackground(Act_Capt_RioMortes.java:237)
   at br.com.flextelecom.barbacena.Actions_Main.Act_Capt_RioMortes$MinhaTask.doInBackground(Act_Capt_RioMortes.java:188)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) 
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088) 
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581) 
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: Reinstale a aplicação e deixe o celular conectado pelo usb, rode a aplicação e cole aqui o erro que aparece no `logcat`.

Comment: Coloque o código da AsyncTask.

Comment: resolvido.  coloquei uma versao anterior do jtds e funcionou.  obrigado

Answer (score 0):

como voce mudou para suportar versoes mais anteriores, pode ter problema de compatibilidade, certifique-se de rodar ele no emulador com a mesma versao do seu celular e veja se aparece o mesmo erro, e quando aparecer, manda a msg do logcat pra gente, assim nao da pra saber o que ta acontecendo.

Comment: Renato, na versao 5.1 ele roda normalmente. estou testando na versao 4.2, 4.1 2 2.3  e nao roda. voce fala em criar um emulador nesta versao para testar?

Comment: este erro da Asynctask vai ate a versaio 4.4

Comment: fiz um teste aqui colocando o emulador na versao 4.3 e 4.4 da um erro na Asynctask

Comment: provavelmente erro de conexao

Answer (score 0):

resolvido.  coloquei uma versao anterior do jtds e funcionou.  obrigado